# AddressBook and Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, indexing, addressbook

I am trying to make an app that will store addressbook contacts' IDs into a SQLite file using core data.

My problem is i will want to request some of those IDs at random, and contact IDs is not reliable because there might be gaps in contacts ID, so i want to have a kind of index attribute that i can do my random on that can never have gaps in the indexes, and if i delete some IDs from my data base, i want to make sure that index  is reindexed (not sure if index is the right name for that, maybe a key).

Does core data implement that automatically? does it create a key for any data model i create by default? if so, can i access that and take advantage of it? what happens if i delete a row?

Sorry it might be a preliminary question.

Also, whats the best way to update my SQLite file when addressbook changes with `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, addressBookChanged, *context)` ? will i have to rewrite the whole addressbook again to my SQLite?

Comment: do you need that "index" attribute only to get random data? or it serves some other purpose as well?

Comment: only to get random data, because if i random on contact ID that i get from addressbook, there is a high chance i will get invalid ID and i will have to find other ID, and this could use sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 1:

Write a fetch request that will return all of your Contact entities. Then use `-countForFetchRequest:` to determine how many you have.

Generate a random integer within the range of your entity count.

Now write another fetch request with `-fetchOffset` equal to that random integer, and `fetchLimit` of 1.

For part 2:
The documentation for `ABExternalChangeCallback` doesn't list any parameter that will denote which objects changed. But you could sort the address book by `kABPersonModificationDateProperty`, and look at records that have changed since the last time you synced up.

Comment: I got that part, thank you.
When the address book gets updated, if i want to just overwrite my whole core data file with my updated Address Book, how can i do that?

Comment: Simplest way would be to recreate the data file from scratch, under a new name. Then close the old one, move new one into place, and reopen. If your rebuild fails for any reason, your original data is still intact and you can try again.